# QT QMainWindow fullscreen without borders

Tags: c++, qt, window, qt-creator, fullscreen

How to do a fullscreen without borders using QMainWindow ? I got a fullscreen including window borders all around the screen. I would like to have a "real" fullscreen like video games. Not a windowed fullscreen.

I tried:

```
MainWindow mainWindow;
mainWindow.setWindowState(Qt::WindowFullScreen);
mainWindow.showFullScreen();
```

MainWindow extend of QMainWindow.

Comment: I realize than it's due to my QGLWidget, i will investigate solutions and find a way to get real fullscreen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to `setWindowFlags`, with `Qt::FramelessWindowHint` and `Qt::CustomizeWindowHint`. So `mainWindow->setWindowFlags(Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::FramelessWindowHint)` should work for you.

Comment: Well, actually i found what is going wrong. This is due to a GLWidget and i didn't found any solutions

Answer (score 1):

I used

```
this->setFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
```

My Window is a QQuickView which is derived from QQuickWindow,QWindow

There is Method

```
QWindow *QWidget::windowHandle() const
```

of your QMainWindow which is derived from a QWidget... (see http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html)

I'm not sure, but you can test the following code:

```
mainWindow->windowHandle()->setFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
mainWindow->windowHandle()->showFullScreen();
```

Answer (score -1):

For Full-Screen :

```
QWidget::showFullScreen();
```

To Exit Full-Screen :

```
QWidget::showMaximized();
```

Comment: 7 years old question ... Your solution is a copy paste from the Qt documentation. I tried the showfullscreen function and post it in my question and it was not the solution.